# Determine devtype and subsystem for laptop power supplies

Tags: udev, libraries

I'm writing a small C program on an Ubuntu machine using `libudev` to monitor for changes to the power supply. At this stage, I just want to successfully detect when the AC adapter is active vs. when the battery is active. I'm adapting code found here for working with `libudev`: http://www.signal11.us/oss/udev/

The linked code sample is working with USB devices, and the function in question (`udev_device_get_parent_with_subsystem_devtype(dev, "usb", "usb_device");`) is what I'm currently trying to alter. After running `udevadm info /sys/class/power_supply/BAT0` (the battery) from the shell I get the following output:

```
P: /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/device:18/PNP0C09:00/PNP0C0A:00/power_supply/BAT0
E: DEVPATH=/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/device:18/PNP0C09:00/PNP0C0A:00/power_supply/BAT0
E: POWER_SUPPLY_CAPACITY=61
E: POWER_SUPPLY_CAPACITY_LEVEL=Normal
E: POWER_SUPPLY_CHARGE_FULL=3850000
E: POWER_SUPPLY_CHARGE_FULL_DESIGN=3950000
E: POWER_SUPPLY_CHARGE_NOW=2365000
E: POWER_SUPPLY_CURRENT_NOW=916000
E: POWER_SUPPLY_CYCLE_COUNT=0
E: POWER_SUPPLY_MANUFACTURER=LGC-LGC3.95
E: POWER_SUPPLY_MODEL_NAME=DELL 92NCT556
E: POWER_SUPPLY_NAME=BAT0
E: POWER_SUPPLY_PRESENT=1
E: POWER_SUPPLY_SERIAL_NUMBER= 5359
E: POWER_SUPPLY_STATUS=Discharging
E: POWER_SUPPLY_TECHNOLOGY=Li-ion
E: POWER_SUPPLY_VOLTAGE_MIN_DESIGN=11100000
E: POWER_SUPPLY_VOLTAGE_NOW=11339000
E: SUBSYSTEM=power_supply
```

So I can tell that the argument for subsystem should be "power_supply", but I'm not sure what to put for "devtype". I have tried "BAT0" and "power" to no avail.

The code spits out:

```
Device Node Path: (null)
Unable to find parent power supply device.
```

This is what it will do if `(!dev)` evaluates true after trying to set `dev` using the function I listed above.

Can someone point me in the right direction for figuring the devtype out for this? Referencing the linked code will be helpful, but I'm finding documentation on this library to be... limited.

Comment: I've worked around this by using `udev_device_new_from_syspath(udev, "/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0");` to get the battery, but I'd still like to know how to determine the devtype in case I wanted to write something else where the absolute path was not known.

Comment: Hmm. `udev_device_get_devtype()` returns `null` on both the battery and ac adapter. From the docs: `Returns: the devtype name of the udev device, or NULL if it can not be determined.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `subsystem` is listed in this line:

```
E: SUBSYSTEM=power_supply
```

However, it appears as if the battery and AC adapter do not have a `devtype` and therefore it is perfectly acceptable to pass `NULL` to the function as an argument in place of a `devtype`.

In this case, the function call looks like this:

```
udev_device_get_parent_with_subsystem_devtype(dev, "power_supply", NULL);
```

If the `udev_monitor*` functions are engaged, it may be easier to filter for `power_supply` events by using:

```
udev_monitor_filter_add_match_subsystem_devtype(mon, "power_supply", NULL);
```